# Adding jar file to each project multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have three projects(Admin,user,viewer) for each of them i added jar files in class path in eclipse. Now i have to use some of admin modules in user and some of admin and user modules in viewer(no cyclic dependency). But is there any way to add jars(which are common for each project at one place). I am packing project classes into jars can i pack the jars also in it?

Comment: Have you seen this option : [User Libraries](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fbuildpath%2Fref-preferences-user-libraries.htm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options how to do this:

1. Create a "common base" project. Add all shared JARs to it and select all the JARs on the "Order & Export" tab in the "Java Build Path" editor. All this base project as a "Project" dependency to all other projects.
2. Create a [User Library](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-user-libraries.htm)
3. Use Maven via the [M2E plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven_Integration) to manage you dependencies

Comment: That's ok if user classes has dependency on Admin i have to add jar file of Admin. Is there any way in maven(like in ant first execute Admin project add that jar to user)

Comment: If you use Maven, then your Admin project will have a "coordinate" (i.e. what you specify as `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`). Just put that as a dependency into the User project and Maven will link the two for you.

Comment: But all 3 projects are packaging as war.

Comment: Split the project into a "code" part which packages as a JAR and a tiny "WAR" project which just depends on the code part. That way, you can have both.

Comment: `<dependency>
     <groupId>com.orgvantage.platform.tabui</groupId>
     <artifactId>tabui</artifactId>
     <type>war</type>
     <classifier>classes</classifier>
     <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>` In User pom.`<attachClasses>true</attachClasses> ` in maven-war plugin configuration. And used mvn clean install on Admin it get local repository for Admin(war). But when i try to compile the User it is showing classes not fount exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bear in mind that while the projects progress more things will become "common". In order to avoid duplication and other problems that might occur I would recommend creating a common project that will contain all the common things like common code (utility classes, common domain etc.), common libraries and other mechanisms.

If you are not using maven, you should consider doing so as it will make your life easier.